# wordpress home static page, and main image, and deleted home

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to remove the default home page, so I deleted it, and now when I browse to my site, I get

```
Not Found
Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.
```

I'm trying to set my website to have a static webpage, and have another tab "latest news" for the blog like functionality, as described in this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

IN the link above they say

> Set the "Home" template to the default template or any custom template

I'm not sure what that means, and how to do it, I went to pages->add page and added a page called **home** and now I see two tabs in the menu called home... I had hoped that my page would be picked up instead of the home I deleted... it did not.

The last thing I was trying to do, is to replace the default image I get in the scheme I chose (twenty ten)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto your wordpress dashboard.
Click on Settings and goto Reading Options and you will see top option about Front Page Displays and it has Your Latest Posts selected. Select the second option which is custom page and choose a page. You might have to create a new page in pages and thats it.

Comment: The page you create can have static content and you can also add it to a new primary menu as home page. On the same screen you can choose another page to be your blog posts page in your example it would be latest news page.

Answer (score 2):

In the directory of your theme create a file (for the purpose of the answer ill call it home-temp.php)
Now inside home-temp.php your insert the following.
[note: the name given in Template Home is the name you will find in wordpress page creator]

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

Your content here.

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now save the file and go to the Add new Page section in wordpress name the page what ever you want and on the theme select Home Page. Now you can go to your settings page and select the newly create page as your static home page.

Good luck ^ ^

Answer (score 0):

The Template is set on the right under "Page Attributes", that' where you set either default or custom template.  This is on the page where you are editing your "Home" page.